# React useEffect to obtain Autocomplete options (material UI) from Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm trying to use react useEffect hook to get data from firestore and give it to the options attribute on a Material UI autocomplete select menu.

I have a collection in my firestore called "organisations". That document has an attribute called "shortName".

I'm trying to get the data from the collection and then use it to set the state on a property called orgList, which I can then use in the in the select menu.

This is what I'm trying.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';
import firebase from "../../../../../firebase";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [orgList, setOrgList] = useState();
  const [selectedOrgList, setSelectedOrgList] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("organisations")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const orgList = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
        setOrgList(orgList)
      })
  }, [orgList])
   
  

  return (
      <div>
      
        <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
        options={orgList}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.shortName}
        renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
            />
            {option.shortName}
            </React.Fragment>
        )}
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} 
            variant="outlined" 
            label="Select Organisation" 
            placeholder="Acme Inc" 
          />
        )}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error message I'm getting says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'shortName' of undefined

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

Using the suggestion from gdh below, this is the next attempt.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';
import firebase from "../../../../../firebase";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [orgList, setOrgList] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOrgList, setSelectedOrgList] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
  const [ error, setError ] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("organisations")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const orgList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          shortName: doc.shortName
        }));
console.log(orgList)

        setOrgList(orgList);
      }, () => {
          setError(true)
        });
        setLoading(false);
        return() => unsubscribe();
    
  }, [orgList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("organisations")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const orgList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          shortName: doc.shortName
        }));
        setOrgList(orgList);
      });
  }, []);

   

  return (
      <div>
      
        <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
        options={orgList}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        getOptionLabel={(orgList) => orgList.shortName}
        renderOption={(orgList, { selected }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
            />
            {orgList.shortName} 
            
            </React.Fragment>
        )}
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} 
            variant="outlined" 
            label="Select Organisation" 
            placeholder="Acme Inc." 
          />
        )}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The console log prints both orgList ids, but the shortName is undefined.

I get an error that says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined .

In an attempt to solve this error, I added:

```
    ignoreCase = {false}
```

to the Autocomplete head tag, but the same error persists. The console logs an error that says:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `ignoreCase` prop on a DOM
> element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
> attribute, spell it as lowercase `ignorecase` instead. If you
> accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
> element

I tried renaming shortName in firestore to 'short' to see if I could avoid the case sensitivity issue, but the same error persists (console logs short as undefined when it has a value in the firestore console).

I know the form is reading from firestore because when I try setting the option as the id of the document, the form loads and the id prints as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what worked - eventually. There seems to be an issue limiting reading single attribute from the firebase document. In my snapshot, I was trying to read: doc.shortName / doc.short. It needs to be:

```
 shortName: doc.data().shortName,
```

I didn't end up needing the second .get useEffect as proposed by gdh.

Here is what worked for me:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';
import firebase from "../../../../../firebase";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [orgList, setOrgList] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOrgList, setSelectedOrgList] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
  const [ error, setError ] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // if (doc.exists) {
      const unsubscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("organisations")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          const orgList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            shortName: doc.data().shortName

          }));
          console.log(orgList)
          setOrgList(orgList);
        }, () => {
          setError(true)
        });
        setLoading(false);
        return() => unsubscribe();
     
    
  }, [orgList]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   firebase
  //     .firestore()
  //     .collection("organisations")
  //     .get()
  //     .then((snapshot) => {
  //       const orgList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
  //         id: doc.id,
  //         ...doc.data()
  //       }));
  //       setOrgList(orgList);
  //     });
  // }, []);

   

  return (
      <div>
      
        <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
        options={orgList}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.shortName}
        renderOption={(orgList, { selected }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
            />
            {orgList.shortName}  
            </React.Fragment>
        )}
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} 
            variant="outlined" 
            label="Select Organisation" 
            placeholder="Acme Inc." 
          />
        )}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As for the toLowerCase error - there is a filterOptions attribute that can be used on Autocomplete. I couldn't figure out how to get that working - but for now, that's a problem for another day.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't have initial values for `orgList`. Provide a blank array.
2. you are only registering `onSnapshot` callback which only executes when `organisations` collection is changed but you are not fetching any data on mount. This means that your autocomplete will only have values when someone make change in `organisation` collection. So maintain another useEffect and fetch the data.

**refactored code**

```js
export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [orgList, setOrgList] = useState([]); 
  const [selectedOrgList, setSelectedOrgList] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("organisations")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const orgList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setOrgList(orgList);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("organisations")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const orgList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setOrgList(orgList);
      });
  }, []);
//.... rest of code...
```

Comment: hmmm - no errors - but the options don't render either. I have a series of warnings that are triggered by using Material UI Typography: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>. I'll try resolving those and testing again before I look further into this. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: I have removed all Typography warnings and am still producing a form without any options (there are 2 in the console).

Comment: I added the next attempt above - along with the error message

Comment: I also tried making a new 3rd organisation to test whether the update might force the form to use the options - but it doesn't

Comment: i see ... as mentioned in the answer, there is no need of dependency `orgList` in the useEffect. It will register new callback whenever data in `organisations` collection changes

Comment: I tried it both with and without the dependency. The same lowerCase error results in both use cases.

Comment: when I console log the snapshot, I can see both org shortNames, but shortName is undefined. I get an error that says: Material-UI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for {"id":"7zKsfdfdfeSDEx7"}.  Thanks anyway for trying to help

Comment: As for the second useEffect you suggested, this seems to be inconsistent with the firestore docs, which say: You can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method. An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.

Comment: and FYI: the reason to add the dependency is  to optimise the hook by only re-running when there is a change in firebase.